# \DeclareSymbolFont{symbols} is not working

Tags: math-mode, fonts

### **Problem Description**

I have been trying to change the math font for a document in TEX but it is not working. After compiling and running my code, I am getting this error/warning `Math formula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts.` at the first formula I put. Also, the `.pdf` output is not showing anything but the number of the page...

Does anyone know what can I do?

### **MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\miletra}{MILETRA}[
  NFSSFamily=MiLetra,
  Path=./,
  Extension=.ttf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*,
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=3},
]

\DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{TU}{MiLetra}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{numbers}{bold}{TU}{MiLetra}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}\mathalpha{numbers}{"30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}\mathalpha{numbers}{"31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}\mathalpha{numbers}{"32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}\mathalpha{numbers}{"33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}\mathalpha{numbers}{"34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}\mathalpha{numbers}{"35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}\mathalpha{numbers}{"36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}\mathalpha{numbers}{"37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}\mathalpha{numbers}{"38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}\mathalpha{numbers}{"39}

\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{TU}{MiLetra}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathsf}{operators}

\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{TU}{MiLetra}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathsf}{letters}

\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}{TU}{MiLetra}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathsf}{symbols}

\begin{document}

$a=123$

\mathversion{bold}

$a=345^\alpha + 2$

\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe you can try `unicode-math` package?

Comment: odd I don't have that font but any other opentype textfont  gives `! Math error: parameter \Umathsup_shift_up\textstyle is not set.`

Comment: The `mathspec` package might actually be more appropriate here.